# ObservableMap of HashMap as value type not triggering MapChangeListener

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to put in place an ObservableMap> that is linked with a listener on my view.

Here it's the code I'm  using:

```
ObservableMap<Integer, HashMap<String, Integer>> map = FXCollections.observableHashMap();

    map.addListener((MapChangeListener.Change<? extends Integer, ? extends HashMap<String, Integer>> change) -> {
        System.out.println("Changed key: " + change.getKey());
    });

    HashMap<String, Integer> store1 = new HashMap<>();
    store1.put("apple", 100);
    store1.put("strawberry", 123);
    store1.put("lemon", 165);
    map.put(1, store1);

    HashMap<String, Integer> store2 = new HashMap<>();
    store2.put("peach", 45);
    store2.put("blackberry", 90);
    store2.put("melon", 10);
    map.put(2, store2);

    HashMap<String, Integer> cpStore2 = map.get(2);
    cpStore2.put("peach", 40);
    map.put(2, cpStore2);
```

And if I execute that I get this :

```
Changed key: 1
Changed key: 2
```

So my issue is that when I do an update on the map there isn't any event triggered. And I'm actually needing this.

Anyone got an idea how I could do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event is just fired if the value changes. But you're putting the same map by the same key. So it is cleare that there is no *change* event. To ensure firing the event you can create a new map with the existing values and putting the new one:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> cpStore2 = new HashMap<String, Integer>(map.get(2));
// cpStore2 is another map than store2 but with the same values
cpStore2.put("peach", 40);
map.put(2, cpStore2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I see the implements of the `ObservableMapWrapper` class which the return of `FXCollections.observableHashMap();`,the following code:

```
@Override
public V put(K key, V value) {
    V ret;
    if (backingMap.containsKey(key)) {
        ret = backingMap.put(key, value);
        if (ret == null && value != null || ret != null && !ret.equals(value)) {
            callObservers(new SimpleChange(key, ret, value, true, true));
        }
    } else {
        ret = backingMap.put(key, value);
        callObservers(new SimpleChange(key, ret, value, true, false));
    }
    return ret;
```

So,you can trigger the listener while add or update a new value.But in your code:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> cpStore2 = map.get(2);
cpStore2.put("peach", 40);
map.put(2, cpStore2);
```

the cpStore2 is old value of the key `2`,you can do this:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> cpStore2 = new HashMap<>();
    cpStore2.put("peach", 40);
    map.put(2, cpStore2);
```

you will trigger the listener.See the result of above code:

```
Changed key: 1
Changed key: 2
Changed key: 2
```

Comment: Yes it could work I would have to add manually each element of my old map to the new one ? Because that would mean a time problem if the map is large ?

Comment: For performance,you can remove the the mapping for key from map.And then the listener should filter operation.For example,`if(change.wasAdded()) {
                    System.out.println("Changed key: " + change.getKey());
                }`